# Date Time Picker on double tap display typing Feature

Tags: codenameone

Currently we are using date with time picker, We looking the feature on this date time picker when double tap used on the Date or Hours or Minutes or AM/PM component.

Is these achieve by using codename one date time picker component?. please help us or guide us how to achieve this.

Please find the screen shot of the date and time picker.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No.

The component looks completely different on an iOS device. We usually recommend using the separate date picker and time picker modes e.g. a time picker on Android looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can I have sample code which works in Android devices example to display date time component like this. As we tried,  we understand it should only on support native platfom. We could not get this type of datetime picker. 


And one more can we make label of the spinner editable on double tapping,  is this possible or not? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need separate pickers one for date and one for time. Android doesn't have a "datetime" picker natively